# Create custom post name while using wp insert

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create custom post_name while using wp insert function but it didn't work and it return my custom only without the post name (slug)

```
$args = array(
                'post_status'  => $status,
                'post_title'   => $title,
                'post_content' => $content,
                'post_name'    => (sanitize_post($post)-$custom_post_name),
            );

            // Insert movie post
            $pid = wp_insert_post($args, true);
            if (is_wp_error($pid)) {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: look the value of `(sanitize_post($post)-$custom_post_name)`

Comment: is this working? What do the two variables have? Does the sanitize function exist? update with more information please

Comment: Only `$custom_post_name` is printed but not the original title or slug @Kaperto

Comment: Yes working but Only $custom_post_name is printed,
`sanitize_post($post) = title,`
`$custom_post_name = numbers,`
and i think the anitize function is exist,
@Kelvin Mariano

Comment: please print the $args variable and put it back in your question

Comment: I fixed, instead of using new code i get the title and use it as post_name @Kelvin Mariano